# How to colorize array of object in chrome console

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I want to get the same results like the regular array of objects print but with color style.
e.g console.log(arrayOfObjects) but blue text

Comment: https://gist.github.com/davidgilbertson/6eae478d9a197bfa1b4dfbef38f787e5

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```js
const arrayOfObjects = [1, 2, 3, 4]

console.log(`%c ${arrayOfObjects}`, 'background: gray; color: blue')
```

(*Open your dev tools to see it in action*)